# grep: output specific line after match

Tags: bash, grep

Is there a way, using grep, to output the line that falls a specific number of lines after the match is found?  For example, I want to output the line with a match, the 8th line after the match, and the 17th line after the match.  Is this possible?

I know I can output the next 17 lines using `grep -A17`, but I want to know if I can get the useful line without everything in between.

Comment: What flavor of *nix and shell are you using?

Comment: bash.  Also, bash for Cygwin, but I'm testing everything on a real linux machine.

Answer (score 3):

Try piping to [awk](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-display-first-ten-lines-1-10-with-numbers-command/print-nth-line-of-file/)  `blah | grep stuff -A17 | awk "NR==1{print} NR==8{print} NR==17{print;exit}"`  This will output the 1st, 8th, and 17th lines only.

If you want to include repeating patterns you can use the mod (%) operator

`awk "(NR-1)%17 == 0{print} (NR-8)%17 == 0{print} (NR-17)%17 == 0{print}"`

Comment: sed: -e expression #1, char 4: unknown command: `,'

Comment: @ewok, my bad, sed prints a range with a comma, oops.

Comment: @ewok I changed it to use awk and 'tested' it this time to make sure it works

Comment: This seems to only print the first occurrence of the match.  Is there a way to print all matches?

Comment: @ewok you're stretching the limits of my awk-fu :)  You can use full on math operators within the awk arguments so that will help, specifically the mod (%) operator.  I have edited my answer to include it.